# How to enable links on top bar submenus in Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation-6

I recently switched to using Foundation 6, and in following an example from the documentation on building a top bar, I discovered that the links on submenus don't work. I see that this issue was brought up on github in [this issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-6/issues/171), but I'm still not clear what is the intended way to handle submenu links in Foundation 6.  This is the example I am using from the documentation, none of the links under the submenu work:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

So I just replaced the foundation.js file (which had been v6.0.1 that I downloaded from the main site) with v6.0.4 from [the foundation-sites github page](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites), and the links work as expected now, apparently v6.0.4 has fixed this.